# AngularJS - Share return values between promises

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I'm making a **get request** to my server, I get the response and I store the value inside a **$scope.productId**

```
  userService.get(true)
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.productId = res.user.productid;
      }
    });
```

then I need to use this value in another **get request** to the api to get the product related to this id.

```
  apiService.get('/product/' + ???)

  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  })

  .catch(function(response) {
  });
```

I'm new to promises, so the objective is to get the value of the first request in to the second one!

Comment: The code that does the second request doesn't have access to `$scope`?

Comment: Hello Frank, no, i get undifined

Comment: `undefined` for `$scope`? or for `$scope.productId`?

Comment: undefined $scope.productId , i can console log $scope

Comment: Can you show how you make both requests? So we can see if you are properly making the 2nd request once the 1st one is actually complete?

Comment: Frank, thanks for all the help. i will do it in another way, the logic change a little bit. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
userService.get(true)
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.productId = res.user.productid;
      apiService.get('/product/' + ???)

      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      })

      .catch(function(response) {
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hello Aagam, thanks for the help, your solution works, but i cannot make it valid because i need to access the $scope value outside

Comment: you can have a callback after all value arrives an in that callback you can use $scope data :)

Comment: Aagam, Thank you very much for your help, i will do this in another way. Thank you once again